# Как организовать ленту событий?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть значения в mySQL таблицах, которые я хочу вывести пользователю в виде ленты.
Эти значения должны отображаться в правильном хронологическом порядке.

пример:

```
$array_1 = $model->users($limit, $offset) // 5 5
// [['created' => 1589230222], ['created' => 1589230100], ['created' => 1589230000]]
$array_2 = $model->orders($limit, $offset) // 5 5
// [['created' => 1589230222], ['created' => 1589230100], ['created' => 1589230000]]
$array_3 = $model->payment($limit, $offset) // 5 5
```

Далее я объединял массивы и сортировал через usort()

Это работает, до тех пор, пока я не сделаю второй запрос с новым offset, где хронология рушится, так как значения в разных таблицах не связаны друг с другом.

Я не понимаю, как мне правильно использовать offset для для таких запросов и как мне создать подобную ленту?

Comment: Что мешает объединить (UNION) и отсортировать (ORDER BY) средствами MySQL, а потом уже получать в PHP?

Comment: Это будет работать примерно так же, как и в моем примере. При первом запросе с нулевым смещением, я получу массив в правильном хронологическом порядке. Но так как данные в таблицах не связаны друг с другом, при новом запросе со смещением в 10, я получу уже неправильный хронометраж относительно первого запроса.

Comment: Это с какого перепугу-то? сначала наборы записей объединяются, и только потом объединённый набор сортируется. Если набор данных не изменился - порядок воспроизводим.

Comment: Например в первой таблице 3 записи от 5, 4, 3 мая. Во второй таблице от 25, 24, 23 апреля. Если я сделаю LIMIT 1 с нулевым смещением я получу две объединенные записи от 5 мая и 25 апреля. Со смещением 1 я получу записи от 4 мая и 24 апреля. В итоге в списке у меня будет хрономитраж: 5 мая - 25 апреля - 4 мая - 24 апреля. Или я не понимая что то? поправьте меня пожалуйста если я туплю

Comment: *Например в первой таблице 3 записи от 5, 4, 3 мая. Во второй таблице от 25, 24, 23 апреля.* После объединения и сортировки получится **один** набор записей, с датами 23.04, 24.04, 25.04, 3.05, 4.05, 5.05. А не два отдельных набора.

Comment: Всё так, при идеальных условиях в один запрос. Но если с каждым новым запросом мы получаем новые наборы данных с новым смещением, которые относительно прошлых запросов невозможно отсортировать.

Comment: Надоело. [UNION clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html). Читайте, пока не поймёте. Особенно начиная с фразы *To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one.*

Comment: спасибо, буду изучать!

Comment: Изучил - Вы были полностью правы. Все работает, уяснил все принципы union. Оформите пожалуйста ответ

Comment: Да нету тут материала на ответ. ИМХО.